# Is there a way to use embedding style syntax for simplifying ( adding namespace to ) multiple class selectors in SCSS?

Tags: class, sass, selector

I have icon classes that contain the `background-image` and `background-size` properties. I want to protect the names of these classes with the prefix `.icon`. Then I can start writing out `.icon.profile`, `.icon.search` etc. selectors. If it were `.icon .profile`, `.icon .search` etc., then I could use embedding is SCSS to neatly protect namespace. However embedding won't work for multiple class selectors, because it selects child nodes. Once I use SCSS, it feels unintelligent to write out the prefix every time. To use embedding in DOM to support embedding in SCSS is an overkill and expensive ( adds unnecessary complexity of DOM elements ).

Is there a way to add "namespace" to classes that compile to multiple class selectors.

```css
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// icons
.icon.search {
  background-image: url(...);
  background-size: cover;
}

.icon.profile {
  background-image: url(...);
  background-size: cover;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, what you are looking for is the [parent selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector) `&`:

```
.icon {
  &.search {
    background-image: url(...);
    background-size: cover;
  }

  &.profile {
    background-image: url(...);
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```